# Cannot migrate custom wordpress modules to a new server

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to migrate a WordPress site to a live server. I've done this numerous times and everything went fine except the custom modules I made for the theme I had to use (Divi) don't work. I am using [this](https://divi.space/blog/adding-custom-modules-to-divi/) guide to load the custom modules. For example what I get on my local development server is:
[image]

And what I'm getting on the live server after migrating is:
[image]

The only difference I could think of is that the live server is using PHP7 and my local one is using PHP5. Could this be the problem? Here's the code I use in my child theme's functions.php:

```
/*================================================
# LOAD CUSTOM MODULES
================================================*/
function Custom_Modules(){
 if(class_exists("ET_Builder_Module")){
 include("/custom-modules/custom-latest-case-studies.php");
 include("/custom-modules/custom-latest-resources.php");
 include("/custom-modules/custom-resources-page.php");
 include("/custom-modules/custom-blog-page.php");
 include("/custom-modules/custom-portfolio-big.php");
 include("/custom-modules/custom-portfolio-small-1.php");
 include("/custom-modules/custom-portfolio-small-2.php");
 }
}

function Prep_Custom_Modules(){
 global $pagenow;

$is_admin = is_admin();
 $action_hook = $is_admin ? 'wp_loaded' : 'wp';
 $required_admin_pages = array( 'edit.php', 'post.php', 'post-new.php', 'admin.php', 'customize.php', 'edit-tags.php', 'admin-ajax.php', 'export.php' ); // list of admin pages where we need to load builder files
 $specific_filter_pages = array( 'edit.php', 'admin.php', 'edit-tags.php' );
 $is_edit_library_page = 'edit.php' === $pagenow && isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) && 'et_pb_layout' === $_GET['post_type'];
 $is_role_editor_page = 'admin.php' === $pagenow && isset( $_GET['page'] ) && 'et_divi_role_editor' === $_GET['page'];
 $is_import_page = 'admin.php' === $pagenow && isset( $_GET['import'] ) && 'wordpress' === $_GET['import']; 
 $is_edit_layout_category_page = 'edit-tags.php' === $pagenow && isset( $_GET['taxonomy'] ) && 'layout_category' === $_GET['taxonomy'];

if ( ! $is_admin || ( $is_admin && in_array( $pagenow, $required_admin_pages ) && ( ! in_array( $pagenow, $specific_filter_pages ) || $is_edit_library_page || $is_role_editor_page || $is_edit_layout_category_page || $is_import_page ) ) ) {
 add_action($action_hook, 'Custom_Modules', 9789);
 }
}
Prep_Custom_Modules();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the brackets at the import lines. PHP7 doesn't like them:

```
/*================================================
# LOAD CUSTOM MODULES
================================================*/
function Custom_Modules(){
 if(class_exists("ET_Builder_Module")){
 include "custom-modules/custom-latest-case-studies.php";
 include "custom-modules/custom-latest-resources.php";
 include "custom-modules/custom-resources-page.php";
 include "custom-modules/custom-blog-page.php";
 include "custom-modules/custom-portfolio-big.php";
 include "custom-modules/custom-portfolio-small-1.php";
 include "custom-modules/custom-portfolio-small-2.php";
 }
}
```